# How can somebody use my domain that I still own to host their website?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I am still in a development phase for a web application I am working on, but I bought a domain on AWS because I wanted to reserve the name. I just visited the website today and was shown an unfamiliar website. I wasn't redirected to another website, and I verified that I entered the domain correctly. I assume somebody is targeted advertising me, and, although very annoying, I was more curious about how this happened. I think they made an alias, but I'm not sure how this was done without having access to my AWS credentials.

Background info: I set up an alias in Route 53 using an IPv4 address to an EC2 instance that has been shut down for a few months. I even tried to acccess that ip address, and nothing showed up, as expected. I then changed the IPv4 address to an EC2 instance that's hosting a different website, and it seems like that new IP address overrides theirs (i.e. the malicious website no longer shows up). Not sure if this is relevant, but I also set up mail on Zoho for that domain a few months back.

Below is a screenshot of said website. Maybe something similar has happened to you and that landing page looks familiar to you? *How* did they do it, and how can I prevent this from happening?

[image]

Edit: After some research, it seems like the terminology is DNS Hijacking. Still would appreciate some knowledge to be shared.

Comment: Can you share the hostname/url?

Comment: It sounds like the old IP address had simply been assigned to another AWS customer. Since you've now changed the DNS record it's too late to trace the DNS lookup to see what was happening. If this happens again, you should first use the `dig` command to gather all the information regarding the resolution of your domain name so that you can see exactly what is happening.

Comment: @MarkB Interestingly, two of my hosted zones are infected by the same landing page, so there is something more fishy going on than old IP address being assigned to another customer. I didn't change the DNS record for one of my hosted zones, so I'll try the `dig` command. Thank you

Comment: @user3788685 The url gives away what my project is about, and I want to keep it low-key. Sorry, but I dont think I can share the hostname although it might help you answer my question. What information were you going to gather from the hostname?

Comment: @user3788685 Neither of them is behind a load balancer. Yes, if I use internal IP addresses, I can see the correct page.

Comment: @PeterKim https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180289/question-52388615

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are unable to share your hostname/url the *first* thing you need to do is test the pages from another location, network and PC browser etc. if your unable too yourself then ask a trusted contact to do it for you.

It *could* be a problem at your end which is causing the 'bad' page to be returned. (I'll start with that);

- You need to check your endpoint for any viruses, [malware](https://www.malwarebytes.com/) or toolbars and addons as any one of these things could cause your requests to be redirected.
- You should check your endpoint and local network for any 'odd' increased load or network traffic (Virus's and malware often exhibit extra traffic and load.
- If you can you should try a different DNS resolver (Google & others provide open DNS resolvers, and as your an AWS customer already they might provide something as well.
- If you wanted to dig deep at the local end you should try something like [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) then you can inspect the actual traffic between you and your AWS instances to make sure the correct/expected data is being sent/received.

At the AWS end, as you have indicated neither instance is behind a load balancer or anything then there are still a number of other things you could check;

- Checking the DNS configuration, have you got the correct name server (`NS`) records listed, are there any wild card entries?
- Is your web server correctly configured being careful to check for any virtual host directives, its also worth checking your web server is actually secure. If your using WordPress or a similar CMS system these are well known for being hacked in a similar way. You should check your actual web dir and make sure all the files and code there is actually yours...
- If you have the option with AWS and you are able check the correct 'good' pages are returned when you use the internal or private addresses of your instances - this may help narrow your searching. If as indicated in our [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180289/question-52388615) that works as expected every time over a few tests then it's unlikely the problem is your actual server serving 'bad' pages.
- If you have any other services running on your instances at the public IP/hostname try and connect directly to those with something like [PuTTY](https://www.putty.org/) and make sure you are actually hitting your server as expected.

In general there are a number of things you can check for which may be causing the issue, and some of the issues it might actually be;

- Check the `http` headers which are coming from the 'bad' pages - they may give a clue where the content is coming from.
- DNS Cache poisoning attack
- DNS Hijacking
- DNS Configuration issue/problem/rouge NS.
- Compromised CMS, 3rd party script or underlying OS.
- MITM Proxy or interception system
- AWS issue

As this setup is not on a server or network fully within your control to speculate as to what else it could be is a little hard. AWS is a big dark cloud and I for one am certainly no expert with there inner workings!

Lastly if you have exhausted all these options and ideas and your still getting the same problems *I'd raise a ticket with AWS* for them to look at. There is every chance that it's just something weird going on within there network somewhere.

Without much more info from your side for people to go and run there own tests and investigations its *very* hard to say where the issue may lie.